# C++ Cannot instantiate abstaract class's child

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I have abstract class Transaction which contains couple of normal properties and methods and one method - Behavior - which I made pure virtual, so the classes which inherits from Transaction can implement it on their own.

My Transaction.h

```
class Transaction abstract{

protected:

...

public:

...

virtual void behavior() = 0;
```

};

I think this should be correct. Than I have class Cow, which I would like to inherit from the Transaction.

This is how I tried to do it

```
class Cow : public Transaction {

    public:
        Cow(int p, Calendar* cal){
        this->priority = p;
        this->cal = cal;
    }

    void Behavior() {

        ...

        do some stuff

        ...

    }
};
```

The problem is, whenever I try to make an object of class Cow. Either it is in Main.cpp or in Cow::Behavior (which are basicly only two places in code I need to be able to create objects of Cow) I end up with an error below.

```
error C2259: 'Cow' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

This really confuses me, as I'm not trying to instantiate an abstract class, but the class that inherits from it. I'm sure this is basic stuff, but I don't seem to be able to solve this problem on my own.

Btw. this is how I try to create new instance of Cow.

```
    Calendar *calendar = new Calendar();
calendar->push(0, new Cow(1, calendar));
```

where the method Calendar::Push accepts

```
void Calendar::push(int t, Transaction *tr)
```

Any ideas?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a pure virtual function `behavior` in the base class, and an unrelated function `Behavior` in the derived class. This doesn't override the pure function since it has a different name. C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: C++ also has the `override` specifier to catch such typos before they make it onto SO :-)

Comment: Thank You Mike. Jesus, I'm stupid, sorry for your time I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is case sensitive. You spelled behavior with lowercase 'b' in your base class and Behavior in the derived one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not overriding the pure virtual function behavior in your class Cow [Behavior is taken as different function] so Cow becomes an abstract class too. And rest are C++ semantics.

Answer (score 0):

First of all C++ has no keyword abstract. It seems you are using C++/CLI. Try the following definitions

```
ref class Transaction abstract{

protected:

...

public:

...

virtual void behavior() = 0;

};

ref class Cow : public Transaction {

    public:
        Cow(int p, Calendar* cal){
        this->priority = p;
        this->cal = cal;
    }

    void behavior() override {

        ...

        do some stuff

        ...

    }
};
```